# SQL statement to select from two tables

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables `employees, salary_advance`.

`employees` table has columns `empid, name, salary` and `salary_advance` has `id, empid, amount, date`

I want to show name, salary, remaining  for all employees ..

```
remaining = ( salary - amount )
```

when I do inner join I get only employees who take advance ..

I want to show who take advance + other employees in employees ..

This is my SQL statement

```
select 
    employees.name , employees.salary , 
    (employees.salary - salary_advance.amount ) 
from 
    employees 
inner join 
    salary_advance on employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

Comment: Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Can an employee get more than one advance?

Comment: I still have problem  . 
yes one employee can get more than one advance . 
I want to show how much he takes and the remaining and the user can specify the date . if no one take advance just show all employees

Comment: when i use where statement I get only employees who take advance 

WHERE  (emp_adv.adv_month >= ?) AND (emp_adv.adv_month <= ?)

Comment: @user1389105 See my answer below, although that builds on the `date` in your schema, not `adv_month`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of your `INNER JOIN`, and you'll also want to use `ISNULL` to get a 0 instead of `NULL` from the `salary_advance` table:

```
SELECT
    employees.name, 
    employees.salary, 
    Remaining = (employees.salary - ISNULL(salary_advance.amount, 0) ) 
FROM 
    employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    salary_advance ON employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: This is for Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: what if I want to use where condition . to show employees who take advance in specific date and the others who don't take . If there is no one take just show all employees in employees table

Answer (score 3):

If an employee can have more than one advance, you'll want to use a `LEFT JOIN` with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to get the correct result. If you need to count only advances since a certain date, add that to the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT employees.name , employees.salary ,
      (employees.salary - COALESCE(SUM(salary_advance.amount),0)) remaining 
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN salary_advance 
  ON employees.empid = salary_advance.empid 
 AND salary_advance.date >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY employees.name, employees.salary
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a1301/1).

Comment: Updated with your date condition.

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join, and take care of the null values:

```
select
  e.name , e.salary,
  employees.salary - isnull(a.amount, 0)
from
  employees e
left outer join
  salary_advance a on e.empid = a.empid
```

The `isnull` function might be named `ifnull`, depending on what database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use:

```
SELECT
    employees.name, 
    employees.salary, 
    ( CASE salary_advance.amount 
          WHEN NULL THEN employees.salary
          ELSE employees.salary - salary_advance.amount
      END  
    ) Remaining
FROM 
    employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    salary_advance ON employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    employees.name , employees.salary , 
    Remaining = (employees.salary - ISNULL(salary_advance.amount, 0))
from 
    employees 
left join 
    salary_advance on employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table, with the matching rows in the right table.

Comment: This gives `NULL` as remaining salary if there is no advance.

Answer (score 1):

Print this:

```
select
    employees.name, 
    employees.salary, 
    Remaining = (employees.salary - ISNULL(salary_advance.amount, 0) ) 
from
    employees 
left outer join
    salary_advance on employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

instead of this:

```
select 
    employees.name , employees.salary , 
    (employees.salary - salary_advance.amount ) 
from 
    employees 
inner join 
    salary_advance on employees.empid = salary_advance.empid
```

Summary: You need to use a `left outer join` instead of `inner join`